# Simple to use, non-invasive JavaScript Call Stack Visualiser?

Tags: javascript, graph, profile, visualize

Can anyone recommend a graphical call stack visualiser for JavaScript, that I can install on a **Linux** box (or is OS neutral)? Preferably one that doesn't involve having to modify the JavaScript being profiled.

I'm after something similar to the graphs produced by `valgrind`/`kcachegrind` but for JavaScript.

**Edit**: A couple of people have suggested the Profile tool of Firebug. I already use this, but unfortunately it's not up to the job I need a visualiser for. E.g. being able to see that a script spends 20% of it's time in the removeListener() function doesn't tell me where that's being called from and help track down potential optimisations (unless I've missed some aspect of the Firebug Profile tab).

Answer (score 1):

Firebug, a plugin for firefox, has a callstack tracker, where you can click on the individual elements of the stack and inspect that context. Maybe not the most visually extravagant call stack inspector in the business, but fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely suggest Firebug as an intermediate solution until you can find something precisely matching your desired output.